# Getting cart empty after redirect issue

Tags: magento-1, redirect

This is the redirect part from my observer:

```
public function _redirectUser(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $sessionUrl = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $lastUrl = $sessionUrl->getData("lastUrl");

        $session->setAfterAuthUrl($lastUrl);
    }
```

The idea is that I check if a user is logged in or not when it access the checkout . If it is not , it will be redirected to login. After login, it will be redirected to `checkout/cart`. This works fine. The problem is that my cart is empty after the redirect. After I refreshed the page, I got all the items from my cart. Why I do not get all of the items from my cart after redirect ? thx